# What does 'Lost 1 Flips' mean in LogCat?

Tags: android, android-webview, android-logcat, ddms

I am periodically seeing this message appear in my LogCat. I've cannot find much information on what it means. Can anyone provide an explanation? I've also searched for the tag in my code but cannot find it.

[image]

My application contains a `WebView` that displays a catalogue of images but does not scroll smoothly. (It does in the Chrome app). I have tried various different combinations of hardware acceleration and cache modes. I have settled on: `WebSettings.LOAD_CACHE_ELSE_NETWORK` and the default `Application` level acceleration, but this is far from perfect performance at the moment. The error seems to sometimes appear when the `WebView` sticks but I don't know if that is the cause.

Comment: Flip refers to switching buffers: https://source.android.com/devices/graphics/architecture.html

Comment: Thanks for the link, that is certainly interesting reading. My question should really be 'how can I avoid losing flips'!

Comment: Just in case anyone finds this in the future, my lost flips seemed to be caused by my app downloading 100+ images at quite high resolution. This was not necessary. The images were re-sampled server side and the performance was greatly improved. Curiously, this issue did not affect rendering the same content in the Chrome app.